# Looping through multiple SQL insert statements using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to loop through a SQL file that has multiple insert statements. I am wanting to check each individual statement because there is a possibility of having duplicate primary keys. What would be the best way to accomplish this task programmatically using C#?

For duplicates, I am needing to skip that query and add the key (Code) to an excel file.

Example of the SQL query:

```
INSERT [dbo].[JuryInstructions] ([Code], [Description], [InstructionText], [EnterUserID], [EnterDate], [UpdateUserID], [UpdateDate], [Type], [InstructionNumber]) VALUES (N'1000A', N'GENERAL INSTRUCTIONS', N'', N'I', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[JuryInstructions] ([Code], [Description], [InstructionText], [Type], [InstructionNumber]) VALUES (N'1001', N'Introduction', N'', N'I', NULL)
```

Comment: So you are trying to read a text file that contains the SQL statements, rather than just data elements? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: We need a sample of the file content

Comment: I was given query statements in the form of an sql file (Washington_Insert_Statements.sql).

Comment: You mean sanity check them before you run them? Lot of hard work with the lifespan of a damsel fly. Tell us more there's bound to be a better way.

Comment: What is the requirement? To change the keys where you find clashes?

Comment: Katherine please edit your question to add information, do not try to put code in a comment box. Also, explain what “to check each individual statement” means.

Comment: You need to read and parse the text file then to extract the data from for the key field and not execute the SQL. Is that correct?

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the questions being asked.

Comment: @NickZimmerman - Yes. That is essentially what I am needing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I quickly hacked together a simple block of code that should give you a basis for building a solution. There are more advanced ways to do it, but I tried to keep this as simple as possible. You should be able to take this with a little work build a solution that does what you want. If anything is unclear, please feel free to ask me.

```
        //open the text file for reading
        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader("Filepath"))
        {
            try
            {
                // read line from text file
                string query = tr.ReadLine();
                // split the string on the commas to make it easier to find the key value
                string[] queryArray = query.Split(',');
                int beginingOfKeyIndex = queryArray[8].IndexOf('\'') + 1; // add one because we don't want the '
                // get the key value from the correct array element
                string keyValue = queryArray[8].Substring(beginingOfKeyIndex, queryArray.Length - beginingOfKeyIndex);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                // we get here when it tries to read beyond end of file or there is some other issue.
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way is just to run each insert statement separately against your db server.  If an error comes back about a primary key violation then you store that particular line off in your log file.

Comment: I will need to do this for multiple servers and there are about a thousand query statements so that will not work.

Comment: A thousand query statements really isn't that much..

Comment: Over multiple servers, that is a lot of time that I don't have. Plus if I can do it programmatically, I can use this in other projects.

Comment: @Katherine, if a thousand query statements over “multiple servers” takes more than a few seconds, you have serious problems with your database. Focus your attention on that instead of messing around with source files.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't take time to write the regular expression to parse out the keyfield (also wasn't sure which field your sample SQL was the key field).

Here is some code to get you started:

```
        try
        {
            Hashtable htKeys = new Hashtable();
            List<string> sqlToExecute = new List<string>();         

            IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines("path-to-your-file.sql");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                // parse out key field here
                string keyfield = RegExToFindYourValue(line);

                if (!htKeys.ContainsKey(keyfield)) 
                {
                    sqlToExecute.Add(line);             
                    htKeys.Add(keyfield, line);
                }
                else
                {
                  // duplicate key, handle here.
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```